# Why does categorical_crossentropy work in when input is not 1-hot encoded?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, loss-function

I'm going through [lessons on the REINFORCE algorithm](https://medium.com/swlh/policy-gradient-reinforcement-learning-with-keras-57ca6ed32555) to solve Cartpole/Pong/etc (using AIGym) and every one uses categorical_crossentropy as the loss function.

What's confusing me is that categorical_crossentropy [expects a 1-hot encoded setup as its true parameter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/categorical_crossentropy). The states being passed in are not 1-hot encoded, they're just the numerical representation of the state of the universe at that moment. Why does this work?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm converts your categorical labels into one hot encode before calculating loss. So you don't have to carry the burden.